# Access remote database MySQL via PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database set up on 000webhost.com. I want to access the data in my database via PHP. I tried:

```
<?php 

include("connect.php");
mysql_select_db("XXXXXXX_users", $con) or die(mysql_error()); 

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY id DESC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))     
{
    $id = $row['id'];
    $user = $row['usrname'];
} 


echo "$user";
?>
```

But it always returns as: "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond."

What do I do?

- I do not have root access
- I'm trying to run the script on Apache

Comment: What's in `connect.php`?

Comment: Apart from your connection issue (which you should fix first), you have a problem in the assignment inside your `while` loop. As it is, your echo would always only output the username with the biggest id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When debugging this sort of thing, it's always good to make sure you can connect using the command line mysql tool first, to rule out issues related to PHP itself.

```
$ mysql -u myuser -h mysql.example.com -p
```

You'll get a more descriptive error message as well, e.g. `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'remote.example.com' (using password: YES)`

If the mysql port is even open on a public interface to begin with (which is usually a terrible idea), mysql itself has its own layer of access control based on the connecting host.  You may need to have an account created specifically with a wildcard hostname, like so:

```
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';
```

The `@'%'` part, specifically, allows connection from any host, local or remote.

Once you can successfully connect from the command line, it's then a simple issue of replicating your command line arguments as arguments to `mysql_connect()`

Comment: Thanks, they have their port closed though, so oh well.

Comment: You can later also do `GRANT ALL privileges ON newdatbase.* TO 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;` and `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`, for database selection if its giving you error.

Answer (score 1):

A lot(if not all?) of hosting providers restrict remote access to the mysql database.  Meaning that you can only connect via localhost.  There is probably a mysql config section on the hosting provider that will allow you to config an ip address from which a certain user can connect from.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Most of hosts doesn't  provide a remote a access to MySQL server's as it a security risk, may you should try another free MySQL server's that allow remote access, try [this](http://www.freemysql.net/v2/) but its a bit slow.