# Connect MySQL database to several domains

Tags: php, mysql, ftp, database-connection

I have two websites with different domains and I have to share data between the two, such as user registered on first website will be login on the second website too.

Is it possible to connect the second website to the first website's MySQL database? I.e. I have two websites `www.example1.com` and `www.example2.com`. Is it possible for `example2.com` to connect to database of `example1.com`?

I use the following PHP code which works fine for `example1.com` but not on `example2.com`:

```
    $conn =mysql_connect("HOST","USERNAME","PASS") or die("cannot connect with db").mysql_error();
    $dbname=mysql_select_db("DATABASE_NAME") or die("Error selecting db").mysql_error();
```

On `example2.com`, the connection fails with error message

> cannot connect with db....

Could you please explain me what is the configuration required for such type of connection and what are the things which may stop this connection?

Comment: What error do you get when you run this on example2.com? There's no reason why this shouldn't work, but there are a few things that might stop it.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, if you have access to MySQL server from the 2-nd website server

Comment: We're talking about different sites. are we talking about different webservers ? What about databases ? Is it the same database server or 2 different ones ? What you want to do is technically possible but will depend on the architecture, and there might be restrictions due to your hosting provider too eventually.

Comment: @andrewsi using above code db is not connected on second site and it dies with message cannot connect with db....will you please explain me what are the configuration required for such type of connection and what are the things which may stop this connection....thanks for help

Comment: @RajuJain Are you using a public webhosting, or do you run your own servers?

Comment: @Mifeet thanks for the comment.... currently i am using a public webhosting for all my sites which are inter-related to each other...same thing i have asked to my domain providers but they charged me for this feature...so is it possible to done this through code...

Comment: @RajuJain If the provider says they charge for this feature then there is no way you can bypass it without ordering the feature.

Comment: @Mifeet...but i think is it possible with a remote database server associated with a particular domain as others are explaining here....i will take a remote database server and connect all my other domains with that,than will my problem solved or not i am confusing with it. Also some of my domains are purchased with different domain provider so i have to shift all the domains to a single provider and it is a hectic job to do...so please give me a solution by which i am able to spend as low as possible and connect all my domains to a common database..thanks for the help

Comment: @RajuJain there may be two problems - (1) the host of your database doesn't allow remote connections, and/or (2) the hosting of your web doesn't allow connection to remote databases. Do you know what the problem is in your case? (You can check (1) by trying to connect to the database from localhost)

Comment: @Mifeet thanks for the reply....i have tried to connect database from localhost but it is not allowed me to connect.....i have also request to my domain provider for a remote database connection....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if the 2 domains are hosted in the same server then no problem at it all you may connect with the database with as much scripts as you want .
if they are in different servers from your database server you can do this but you have allow remote connection for each script IP

Answer (score 2):

It depends on where you host your database and your website. Some webhostings allow only local database connection. So make sure that either both websites are on the same server or that your settings allow you to connect from your PHP code to the remote database and the database allows remote connection.

If you have command-line access to your webserver, check that you can connect using `mysql` command - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5602492/2032064).